# How can you manually reorder a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in Android that needs to have the ability to be manually reordered. An example would be within Android's Music Player application, when you can change the order of tracks in a playlist. I know how to programmatically change the order of a ListView, but not how to do it in regards to a touch and slide approach that can be found in the Music Player application.

Thanks in advance,

groomsy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in the framework for this at the moment, you'll need to look at the [Music source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master) to get an idea of how to implement this. You can also, of course, copy over parts of the relevant implementation as you see fit.