# android how to write drag n drop for my given application

Tags: android

I have done todo list application. All aree did but one extra thing I want to do, in my app HomeActivity contains tasks as listview(single item consists a checkbox, a textview, a imageview) I want drag n drog of items. 
Externaly how to do drag n drop I got but I want to add that into my codes. Please gothrough my code I given below & suggest me where I made change for drag n drop.

### DBAdapter.java(Database)

package com.v3.todo;

import android.R.string;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
    // Initial Configuration
    public static final String DB_NAME = "To-Do";
    private static final int DATABASE_VER = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

```
private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

// Set the Tables Key Words
public static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";

// Table Queries
private static final String CREATE_TASKS = "CREATE TABLE tasks (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, todo TEXT, date_create TEXT, date_completed TEXT, completed INTEGER, orderId INTEGER NOT NULL);";

// Keys
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TODO = "todo";
public static final String KEY_DATECREATE = "date_create";
public static final String KEY_DATECOMPLETED = "date_completed";
public static final String KEY_COMPLETED = "completed";
public static final String KEY_ORDER = "orderId";

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tasks");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return this;
}

public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

// Custom Methods

// Insert data to Task table
public long insertINtask(String taskNm, String dtCreate, String dtComplete,
        int completed, int order) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TODO, taskNm);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATECREATE, dtCreate);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATECOMPLETED, dtComplete);
    initialValues.put(KEY_COMPLETED, completed);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ORDER, order);
    return db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, initialValues);
}

// Get Last priority
public int getLastPriority() {
    int maxOrder = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    Cursor cr=null;
    try{
    cr = db.rawQuery("select max(" + KEY_ORDER + ") from "
            + TABLE_TASKS, null);
    cr.moveToFirst();
    System.out.println("rawQuery: " + "select max(" + KEY_ORDER + ") from "
            + TABLE_TASKS);
    System.out.println("Max order= " + cr.getString(0));
    if (cr.getString(0) == null)
        maxOrder = 0;
    else
        maxOrder = Integer.parseInt(cr.getString(0));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Within DBAdapter " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        cr.close();
    }
    return maxOrder;

}

// Get Uncompleted Tasks
public Cursor getUncompletedTask() {
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_TODO },
            KEY_COMPLETED + "= 0", null, null, null, null, null);
    c=db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[]{ID,KEY_TODO},KEY_COMPLETED + "= 0", null, null, null, KEY_ORDER + " ASC" ,null);
    return c;
}

// Get Completed Tasks
public Cursor getCompletedTask() {
    return db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_TODO },
            KEY_COMPLETED + "= 1", null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Get Task Id
public Cursor getTask_ID(String taskNm) {
    return db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_TODO }, KEY_TODO
            + "= '" + taskNm + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Get Task-Name
public Cursor getTask_Name(int TID) {
    return db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_TODO }, ID + "= "
            + TID, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//Get Order
public Cursor getOrder(int TID) {
    return db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_ORDER }, ID + "= "
            + TID, null, null, null, null, null);
}
// Edit Task-Name
public boolean updateTaskNm(int TID, String taskNm) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TODO, taskNm);
    return db.update(TABLE_TASKS, initialValues, ID + "=" + TID, null) > 0;
}

// Delete a record
public boolean deleteTask(int TID) {
    return db.delete(TABLE_TASKS, ID + "=" + TID, null) > 0;
}

// Make Unmark to a task
public boolean unMarkTask(int TID,String dtCreate) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_COMPLETED, 0);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATECREATE, dtCreate);
    return db.update(TABLE_TASKS, initialValues, ID + "=" + TID, null) > 0;
}

// Set Task complete
public boolean setTaskComplete(int TID, String dtComplete) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_COMPLETED, 1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATECOMPLETED, dtComplete);
    return db.update(TABLE_TASKS, initialValues, ID + "=" + TID, null) > 0;
}

//Update Order
public boolean setOrder(int OId,int TID) {
    System.out.println("==== OID="+OId+" TID="+TID);
    if(db==null)
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(!db.isOpen())
        open();

    boolean f=false;
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ORDER, OId);
    db.execSQL("update "+TABLE_TASKS+" set "+KEY_ORDER+"="+OId+" where _id="+TID);
    //f= db.update(TABLE_TASKS, initialValues, ID + "=" + TID, null) > 0;

    return f;
}
//Get orders between--Not used
public Cursor getBetweenOrders(int fOrder,int tOrder) {
    return db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { ID, KEY_ORDER }, KEY_ORDER + " BETWEEN "+fOrder +" AND "+tOrder, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//Update all orders--not used
public boolean setAllOrders(int[] TID, int[] orderid,int count) {
    boolean f=false;
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        initialValues.put(KEY_ORDER, orderid[i]);
        f= db.update(TABLE_TASKS, initialValues, ID + "=" + TID[i], null) > 0;
    }
    return f;
}
```

}

### HomeActivity.java

package com.v3.todo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {
    DBAdapter db;
    Cursor cr;
    CheckBox[] chk;
    static String[] valChk;
    static int Task_Id, taskId;
    static int[] idchk;
    EditText edTask;
    Button btnAdd;
    String newTask = "";
    int order;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
     static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0, DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

```
String date = "", time = "", dateTime = "";
// ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
static ArrayList<Task> m_tasks = new ArrayList<Task>(), t_tasks = null;
TaskAdapter m_adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.setTitle("To-Do Lists");

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    edTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddTask);
    edTask.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus == true) {
                if (edTask.getText().toString()
                        .compareTo("Add task here...") == 0) // default text
                {
                    edTask.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    db = new DBAdapter(HomeActivity.this);
    m_tasks = getTasks();

    if (m_tasks.size() != 0) {
        this.m_adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, R.layout.addchecktomain,
                m_tasks);
        // lv1.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
        System.out.println("creating");
        setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    } else {

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("No To-Do Lists");
        tv.setTextSize(22);
        rl.addView(tv);
    }
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            newTask = edTask.getText().toString();

            String min = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            String hr = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            String dd = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
            String mm = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            String yyyy = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            if (min.length() == 1)
                min = "0" + min;
            if (hr.length() == 1)
                hr = "0" + hr;
            if (dd.length() == 1)
                dd = "0" + dd;
            if (mm.length() == 1)
                mm = "0" + mm;
            String dtCreate = mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy + " " + hr + ":"
                    + min;
            if (newTask.equals("")) {
                alertboxNeutral("Warning", "Task should not be empty!",
                        "Okay");
            }
            else if (newTask.length() < 2) {
                alertboxNeutral("Warning",
                        "Task should not be less than 2 Letters", "Okay");
            } else {
                try {
                    db.open();
                    long id1;
                    order = db.getLastPriority();
                    if (order == 0)
                        id1 = db.insertINtask(newTask, dtCreate, null, 0, 1);
                    else
                        id1 = db.insertINtask(newTask, dtCreate, null, 0,
                                order + 1);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Within AddTask HomeActivity " + ex.toString());
                } finally {
                    db.close();
                }
                alertboxNeutral("Success", "Saved.", "Okay");
            }
        }
    });
}

// Method to fetch Uncompleted tasks from db with ID
public ArrayList<Task> getTasks() {
    t_tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    try {
        db.open();
        cr = db.getUncompletedTask();
        if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Task t1 = new Task();
                String[] str = new String[2];
                str[0] = cr.getString(0);
                str[1] = cr.getString(1);
                t1.setTaskID(cr.getString(0));
                t1.setTaskName(cr.getString(1));
                t_tasks.add(t1);
            } while (cr.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Within Home " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        cr.close();
        db.close();
    }

    return t_tasks;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Task");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    System.out.println("v.getId=" + v.getId());
    Task_Id = (Integer) v.getTag();

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.edit_task:
        Intent i1 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, EditTaskActivity.class);
        i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i1);

        return true;
    case R.id.delete_task:
        // database functions
        boolean f = false;
        try {
            db.open();
            f = db.deleteTask(Task_Id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Within Home " + ex.toString());
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
        if (f == true)
            alertboxNeutral("Success", "Deleted.", "Okay");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void alertboxNeutral(String title, String message, String positive) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            HomeActivity.this);
    if (title.equals("Warning")) {
        alertbox.setTitle(title);
        alertbox.setMessage(message);
        alertbox.setPositiveButton(positive,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                HomeActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
        alertbox.show();
    } else if (title.equals("Success")) {
        alertbox.setTitle(title);
        alertbox.setMessage(message);
        alertbox.setPositiveButton(positive,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                                HomeActivity.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
        alertbox.show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.add_task:
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AddTaskActivity.class);
        i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i1);
        break;
    case R.id.list_completed:
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ListCompletedActivity.class);
        i2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i2);
        break;
    case R.id.rearrange:
        Intent i3 = new Intent(this, RearrangeActivity.class);
        i3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i3);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

/*
 * @Override protected void onPause() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 * super.onPause(); finish(); }
 */

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        db.open();
        m_tasks = getTasks();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Within Home " + ex.toString());
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    m_adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, R.layout.addchecktomain, m_tasks);

    System.out.println("notify data changed");
    // m_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    // m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);
    super.onResume();

}

/*
 * @Override public void onBackPressed() { // TODO Auto-generated method
 * stub db.open(); m_tasks = getTasks(); db.close();
 * System.out.println("notify data changed on back pressed");
 * m_adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 * super.onBackPressed(); }
 */
 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                            mDateSetListener,
                            mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                ((TimePickerDialog) dialog).updateTime(mHour, mMinute);
                break;
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                break;
        }
    }    

private void updateDisplay() {
    //edTask.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" ").append(pad(mHour)).append(":").append(pad(mMinute)));

    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    c.clear();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, mHour);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
    Intent activate = new Intent(this, getClass());
    AlarmManager alarams ;//=  (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, activate, 0);
    alarams = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarams.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis()
            + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);*/
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in 10 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinute = minute;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
```

}

### Task.java

//Class for getting value from HomeActivity and set into the two variables

package com.v3.todo;

public class Task {
String TaskNm;
String TaskId;

public String getTaskName() {
    return TaskNm;
}
public void setTaskName(String TaskNm) {
    this.TaskNm = TaskNm;
}
public String getTaskId() {
    return TaskId;
}
public void setTaskID(String TaskId) {
    this.TaskId=TaskId;
}
}

### TaskAdapter.java

package com.v3.todo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import com.v3.todo.DragNDropAdapter.ViewHolder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public final class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList tasks;
    Context context1;
    CheckBox chk;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView imgAlram;
    DBAdapter db;
    static int TaskId;
    static int RId;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    boolean f = false;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1, DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    String date = "", time = "", dateTime = "";

```
public TaskAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, tasks);
    this.tasks = tasks;
    context1 = context;
    RId = textViewResourceId;
}

public int getCount() {
    return tasks.size();
}

public Task getItem(int position) {
    return tasks.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;
    final int dbid;
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Task t = tasks.get(position);

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context1
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.addchecktomain, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(t.getTaskId());
        v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            System.out.println(convertView.getTag());
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

    if (t != null) {
        chk = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cboTask);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTask);
        imgAlram = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageAlram);

        if (chk != null) {
            chk.setId(Integer.parseInt(t.getTaskId()));

            chk.setText("");
            // chk.setTag(Integer.parseInt(t.getTaskId()), t.getTaskName());

            chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    int taskId = buttonView.getId();
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // /call setTaskComplete(i)
                        // / reset list view or refresh list view
                        String min = Integer.toString(c
                                .get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        String hr = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                        String dd = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
                        String mm = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                        String yyyy = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                        if (min.length() == 1)
                            min = "0" + min;
                        if (hr.length() == 1)
                            hr = "0" + hr;
                        if (dd.length() == 1)
                            dd = "0" + dd;
                        if (mm.length() == 1)
                            mm = "0" + mm;
                        String dtComplete = mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy
                                + " " + hr + ":" + min;
                        try {
                            db = new DBAdapter(context1);
                            db.open();
                            f = db.setTaskComplete(taskId, dtComplete);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("Within Home "
                                    + ex.toString());
                        } finally {
                            db.close();
                        }
                        if (f == true) {
                            // HomeActivity.referesh = 1;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context1,
                                    HomeActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            // HomeActivity.
                            context1.startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(context1, "Task Completed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (tv != null) {
            tv.setText(t.getTaskName());
            dbid = Integer.parseInt(t.getTaskId());
            tv.setTag(dbid);

            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            context1,
                            "You have chosen the task: " + " "
                                    + v.getTag().toString() + "  Id: "
                                    + dbid + "::" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    tv.setHighlightColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
                }
            });
            ((Activity) context1).registerForContextMenu(tv);
        }
        if (imgAlram != null) {
            imgAlram.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Write ur code here
                    Toast.makeText(context1, "You have chosen the Alram ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ((Activity) context1).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                    ((Activity) context1).showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
}
```

}

### mai.xml

−



−

### addchecktomain.xml

−

−

−

Change required for HomeActivity & TakAdapter.java (getView())
Please tell me in my above application what should be write so that listitems can drag n drop .
Thanx

Comment: do you really think that somebody will read all this?

Comment: Protip: Try to pare your pasted code to the minimum in order to describe or duplicate your issue.  Dumping all your code into a question is more likely to scare off potential help.  Also, the act of cutting down your code can sometimes help you determine what the actual problem is. I would **strongly** suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not read your full post but what I understand is that you want to make your ListView drag and drop.

The is no standard component to do this but you can use the TouchInterceptor class in the standard Music app.

This subject has been already questioned and answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899035/how-can-you-manually-reorder-a-listview-in-android) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940117/android-drag-and-drop-list-rearrange). In the second link there is all the information you need.